How to deal with tags that can have various meanings?
There is a tag for replication, which in quant usually refers to replication of a portfolio. It can however also refer to replication of a scientific study as it is used in the question Is there a website that lists replication code of financial papers? The question How do I reproduce the cross-sectional regression in “Intraday Patterns in the Cross-section of Stock Returns”? uses the term "reproduction" in the same sense of replication of a scientific study. When I asked how to identify studies that should be replicated I added the tag "replication" to it and noticed that I did not use it in the sense as it is usually used here. There also so far is no user guidance how to use it. Would it be good to write that it refers to portfolio replication and start a new one called "reproduction" even though that term is not as common? Or would it be possible to fork the tag?
As it raised some concerns in the economics stack exchange that I add content here on a topic on that I founded a web project that I linked to in several questions I would like to point out that - as you can already see by clicking on my name - I founded the ReplicationWiki (for replication of scientific studies). So it is my area of expertise, and I hope it is welcome here if I contribute what I know.

A quick glance at Meta.StackExchange suggests that using more specific tags is the way this is solved elsewhere. This seems like a sensible idea to me. This will require some re-tagging but this is manageable. I hope to pick this up this week.
Of course, you're contributions on replication (an important topic IMO) are welcome when relevant but disclosing affiliation in those contributions is required. 
